# What is the best way to update the value of an input field in a long list of input fields with React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a long list of items that includes an input field on each item. The value of each input field is set as follows (in simplified form):

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    value: ''
});

function handleChange (value) {
    setState({value: value});
}

<input value={state.value} onChange={(e) => {handleChange(e.target.value)}} />
```

This works fine for one input, but starts to slow down significantly when there are lots of items in my list. That is, there is a noticeable delay when the user types in the input field. Is there a better way to handle state changes like this to make it more performant?

Comment: Please provide how these components are rendered ? ie by their parent.

Comment: You could use uncontroled inputs, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal, rendering a large set of components will not go in a flash: React will need time to loop through all your components to render them. Please note that dev mode is much slower because react does a lot of checks that are not done in dev mode.

To solve your problem, I recommend one of the following methods:

1. Paginate your items, render only a few items in an infinite scroll list.
2. The state change of inputs should be in the inputs and the whole tree should not be rendered each time.
3. Defer the render of your components. There is a package called [react-defer-renderer](https://github.com/incepter/react-defer-renderer#readme) that orchestrates the deferring of trees and could potentially help in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the info. We're moving from Angular to React, and honestly, this is something that I think Angular does better. I'll check out the react-defer-renderer package.

Comment: Also, Please note that there are several other packages that does something that could work for you: react-window and react-virualize. The difference is that they render only the part of the screen that needs to be rendered (if you ctrl+f in your screen, you will not find an element that is not visible) defer-render will render gradually. Besides, I am sur that in production mode you won't notice the lag unless you have 20000+ element

Comment: I notice an extraordinary lag with just 4 or 5 items on the page. As I'm typing I don't see what I typed until about 1-2 seconds later. I'll also look into the react-window and react-virualize packages you mentioned. How can I run in production mode while on my local environment? My app was created using create-react-app.

Comment: May be there is something wrong with your setup, could you please copy some of your code to codesandbox and share it with me ?